# how to alter table to add the constraint on a existing column

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

Alter EMP_BACKUP table to add the following constraint.
Job column should take any of the following values only (CLERK, SALESMAN, MANAGER, ANALYST, PRESIDENT)

how to add constraint on a job column which take values (CLERK, SALESMAN, MANAGER, ANALYST, PRESIDENT) only.

```
alter table EMP_BACKUP add job
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877):

```
alter table emp_backup
add constraint chk_job check (job in ('CLERK', 'SALESMAN', 'MANAGER', 'ANALYST', 'PRESIDENT'));
```